# Date diffrent function showing error in my live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is the code of my block it gives error

```
$inti_date=strtotime($row->inti_date);
$inti_date=date('Y-m-d',$inti_date);
$diff=date_diff($today,$inti_date);
$temp = $diff->format("%a");
```

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: Chances are that the $row->inti_date is wrong to start with. What is the error displayed ? Can you echo/log the $row->inti_date variable before it is used and in the condition of the error ?

Comment: And what is in `$row->inti_date` and `$today`

Comment: When you say _Showing error in my live server_ Do you also mean that this code works on your TEST Server?

Comment: @ RIggsFolly $row->inti_date is contain date from database

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are dealing with a date from your database and want to remove the time portion from a DateTime column.

If you notice the prototype for date_diff

> DateInterval date_diff ( DateTimeInterface $datetime1 , DateTimeInterface $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = false ] )

`date_diff` requires the dates to be of type DateTimeInterface therefore the dates need to be created using the DateTime Class

```
// fake an object just for testing
$row = new stdClass();
$row->inti_date = '2017-05-01 10:10:10';

$inti_date = new DateTime($row->inti_date);
// I assume you were just after the data portion in both cases
// So set time to 0 o'clock
$inti_date->setTime(0,0,0);

$today = new DateTime('now');
// set time to 0 o'clock
$today->setTime(0,0,0);

$diff      = date_diff($today,$inti_date);
$temp      = $diff->format("%a");

echo $temp;

// or you could code the diff processing like this
$diff = $today->diff($inti_date);
echo $diff->format("%a");
```

Result on 04/05/2017 is

```
3
```